# Solr Distributed Search returns Empty document list

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am running Solr (4.10) in cloud mode by configuring multiple collections (1 for each day). Structure is as shown below. I can fetch documents for given query, if I query individual collection. However when I send distributed request to multiple shards, I only see numFound and no documents returned. Appreciate any pointers on setup.

I also tried by creating alias which covers multiple collection. But still same result.

```
--- directory structure:
    solr
        collection1                   //(does not have any index)
        collection_20150112
        collection_20150113
```

Command to run Solr:
sh bin/solr restart -d example -cloud -p 9999 -noprompt

```
Set up RequestHandler called alias in solrconfig.xml of collecton1

  <requestHandler name="/alias" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="fl">score,*</str>
       <str name="shards">http://localhost:9999/solr/collection_20150113,http://localhost:9999/solr/collection_20150112</str>
     </lst>

http://localhost:9999/solr/collection1/alias?q=domain:com&debug=false&shard.info=true&fl=*
e.g
{
responseHeader: 
{
status: 0,
QTime: 19,
params: 
{
q: "domain:com",
debug: "false",
shard.info: "true"
}
},
response: 
{
numFound: 11696,
start: 0,
maxScore: 1.3015664,
docs: [ ]
}
}
```

However if ask for fl=id, than id's are returned
http://localhost:9999/solr/collection1/alias?q=domain:com&debug=false&shard.info=true&fl=id

```
{
responseHeader: {
status: 0,
QTime: 9,
params: {
fl: "id",
q: "domain:com",
wt: "json",
rows: "2"
}
},
response: {
numFound: 1386,
start: 0,
maxScore: 2.164481,
docs: [
{
id: "1c3781d3-bb28-4060-9150-09b0cc9d0084"
},
{
id: "d3e45451-0b75-4eb2-9740-3a139c182359"
}
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, so I had the same issue.  The solution was provided here: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-4-3-1-query-does-not-return-documents-just-numFounds-2-shards-replication-Factor-1-td4081073.html

Basically my unique ID was utilizing a case-insensitive string type, which caused issues on get fields look up.  Changing the UID field to a "string" corrected the get fields look up and fixed the empty documents list.